# How to Change Background image of a UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I'm creating hundreds of dynamic `UIButtons` in my application. While creating these `UIButtons` I gave a tag to each one.
What I want to do is to be able to change the background image of the `UIButton` on click. 
If I have a `UIButton` with a tag than how can I change the background image of the `UIButton`?

Comment: You should do a little research before asking a questions, there are literally hundreds of blogs out there covering this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can Change the Button image By Sender tag  Like :

```
 -(IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender

    {
  [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",[sender tag]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
```

if You have All the Image Names in a Array Then You can Do as Below.

```
-(IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender

    {
  [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[MyImagearray ObjectAtindex:[sender tag]]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
```

if this is Not what you want then specify your Question properly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You could shorten this even more by just taking `[sender tag]` and placing it where tagnum is. Then the whole thing is on one line.

Comment: if i have tag in int variable than how can i do ?? like example i have  "int x;" than i give value to x "x = 10;" now how can i change background image of button which have tag value "x"...

Comment: use my first method `[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",[sender tag]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways that this can be done when you click a button but two of the best ways would be to ever put it into a `switch statement` like so

```
- (IBAction)shouldChangeImage:(id)sender
  {
       switch([sender tag]) {
             case 1:
                   [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myFirstImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                   break;
             case 2:
                   [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mySecondImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                   break;

             // And so on for each button tag and then have a default for those that are not listed.

             default:
                   [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myDefaultImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                   break;
       }
  }
```

This is not good for hundreds of buttons, but would still work. This would also be the best way if all your images where named completely different, but if you named your images the same and just prefixed them with the tag number that would create more efficient code and it would be easier to read. You would do this like so.

```
- (IBAction)shouldChangeImage:(id)sender
  {
      [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImage-%d.png",[sender tag]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }
```

Notice how the whole thing is on one line so this is easier to read and is more efficient.

You could also use an `else if statement` but if you have hundreds I would recommend the one line way.

Hope this helps

Comment: He is trying to add 100 or more buttons so Switch Statement is not well in that case.

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota Agreed added just as an option nothing more, then he can make his mind up which one to use. I always like to give a couple of ways to give the person an option which would suit them best. I do recommend the shorter way though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to change the background image of button:

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *) forState:(UIControlState)]
```

also you should go through [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)btnclicked:(id)sender

    {

   int tag=sender.tag;

  UIImage * newImage=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",tag]];
  [sender setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
///This bellow line for Normal Image with button tag just put image with tag and add Normal.
         [yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dNormal.png",btnGo.tag]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

///This bellow line for UIControlStateHighlighted Image with button tag just put image with tag and add Highlited.
        [yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dHighlited.png",btnGo.tag]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

///This bellow line for UIControlStateSelected Image with button tag just put image with tag and add Selected.

        [yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dSelected.png",btnGo.tag]] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

and in your button clicked method just set it as a selected..

**For EX:**

```
-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender{
       UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
       [btn setSelected:YES];

}
```

Comment: @Vishal this code is for whole state and also whole button with its separate image also put static name for image here but its working see..

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if(photo.tag==TagNum) [photo setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: This code giving warning "Class method '+viewWithTag:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"  This code can help me if warning is solved

Comment: What's photo? Please provide more info. Very short and doesn't really say whats going on.

Comment: Photo is the button of which you compare the tag.